# tkinter access child from parent

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I have a master canvas

```
canvas = Canvas(root,width=1200,height=800)
```

and a lot of child widgets such as lists and frames and canvases inside frames

I want to write a function that gives in just the parent canvas and access the child in a form like

```
def showInstrumentList(canvas):
    child_listbox = canvas.listbox <== this kind of approach (not real code)
```

I have a lot of child widgets spread across my program and i really need a way to access these child widgets from the top down. (So everything starting from the parent and finding its way down)

Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
canvas = Canvas(root,width=1200,height=800)
canvas.label = Label(canvas)
```

You can add new attributes.